# Twitter Streaming without Keyword

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm trying to stream Twitter using Tweepy and I was wondering if it is possible to stream without giving a keyword? Therefore I would be able to stream all tweets instead of only ones with a given keyword. The code I'm following can be found here: https://gist.github.com/bonzanini/af0463b927433c73784d Someone commented saying that this isn't possible and I just wanted to double check that this is true or if there is a work around without having to buy the Firehose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access a *sample* of all tweets by using this endpoint

`https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/reference/get/statuses/sample`

As is made clear in [the documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/reference/get/statuses/sample):

> Returns a small random sample of all public statuses.

If you want *all* tweets then, yes, you need to pay for access.